# Banner image on responsive website overwriting logo and header text on mobile view, how to load image to avoid this?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, responsive-design

Currently when my site [www.supplementbox.co](http://www.supplementbox.co) is viewed on mobile, the banner image becomes overlayed with the logo and header text. On desktop view this isn't a problem. How can I load the image on mobile so as to fix this problem? What's the best solution? Keep in mind I need to keep the same image, but possibly find a way to display it differently. would i need to specify a different image per viewport, or specify to load it differently? how can i solve this problem while maintaing the same image on desktop view?

Comment: Can you add code? and what you tried to do to fix this?
I could not find anything wrong on Android or Chrome Mobile View.

Comment: In firefox responsive design view I don't see a problem either.

Comment: The problem is that the image is overlaying text and this makes the text unreadable. How can I change the image so it overlays the text in a different way. Or what other solution is available to solve the problem of the overlaying text being unreadable?